# comparing multiple values to eachother in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

I want to compare 10 values to eachother and when they are NOT equal he shall do some stuff...

```
if ($a!=$b!=$c!=$d!=$e!=$f!=$g!=$h!=$i!=$j)
{ 
 // do some stuff
}
```

It ain't worked... so I thought, I probably can't compare multiple values to each other..
so I tried that:

```
if ($a!=$b&&$a!=$c&&$a!=$d&&$a!=$e&&$a!=$f&&$a!=$g&&$a!=$h&&$a!=$i&&$a!=$j&&
    $b!=$c&&$b!=$d&&$b!=$e&&$b!=$f&&$b!=$g&&$b!=$h&&$b!=$i&&$b!=$j&&
    $c!=$d&&$c!=$e&&$c!=$f&&$c!=$g&&$c!=$h&&$c!=$i&&$c!=$j&&
    $d!=$e&&$d!=$f&&$d!=$g&&$d!=$h&&$d!=$i&&$d!=$j&&
    $e!=$f&&$e!=$g&&$e!=$h&&$e!=$i&&$e!=$j&&
    $f!=$g&&$f!=$h&&$f!=$i&&$f!=$j&&
    $g!=$h&&$g!=$i&&$g!=$j&&
    $h!=$i&&$h!=$j&&
    $i!=$j) 
{
 // do some stuff
}
```

But he's still ain't doing anything...
I'm 100% sure that the case happens that they are all not equal^^

Comment: So basically `not(a==b==c==d==e...)`. Why are all those values not in an array? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discover arrays:

php 5.4+

```
if([$a, $b, $c, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j] === array_unique([$a, $b, $c, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j]))
{
   //do stuff
}
```

php < 5.4

```
if(array($a, $b, $c, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j) === array_unique(array($a, $b, $c, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j)))
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Alma Do Mundo, thank you for introducing me to the short array syntax.

Comment: @TecBrat thanks for the edit. Sometimes I forget that not all have latest PHP version

Answer (score 2):

Put your values in an array and then use this condition:

```
if (count(array_unique($arr)) != 1) {
    // at least one value is different
}
```

If all values must be different you can use this:

```
if (count(array_unique($arr)) === count($arr)) {
    // all values are different
}
```

Comment: No, OP wants they all be unequal (see `&&` in condition)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo This is correct imho. If they're all equal, `count()` will be `1`.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo the count will be greater than 1, if the values would be unequal, it'll return 1 only if all values are same in array, thats why I have put != 1, I guess am not wrong...sorry

Comment: @Jack - I'm not sure. Assume `$a=1; $b=2; $c=3; $d=1` - this will not fit OP's request since `$a==$d`, but `count(array_unique($arr))` will result in `3`

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo But `$a != $b`, so not *all values* are equal.

Comment: @Jack well, it may be E_TOO_COMPLCATED for me in second OP's code (there he clearly uses `&&` - which indicates for me that they _all_ must be unequal)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I would agree that it's somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (count(array_unique($arr) == count($arr))`?

Comment: @invisal That's the other way; I've edited that into the answer :)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo  so basically the requirement was if all values are unequal instead of even a single value unequal ?